# Android: Displaying a view over ViewCard

Tags: android, android-layout, android-5.0-lollipop, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I want to achieve this (ribbon over a CardView):
[image: expected]

And here's the snippet of my solution:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/testId"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ribbonParentId"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="left|top"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:background="@drawable/green_ribbon" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/ribbonId"
        style="@style/RibbonStyle"
        android:text="@string/ribbon_text" />
</LinearLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/historicalWeightCardViewId"
    style="@style/MyCardViewStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp" >

          ... Other elements

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

And in the RecycleView adapter I bring the ribbon to front by calling.

```
itemView.findViewById(R.id.ribbonParent2Id).bringToFront();
```

My solution is working in most devices I tested except Nexus 5 (Android 5.1.1), where ribbon is still (partially) behind the cardview. I'm using AppCompat and targeting >v4.0.

1. What is the proper way of putting a view over a cardview?  Is there another way of achieving the same thing?  Why my solution doesn't work for some cases?
2. How can I make green ribbon to start from the left edge of the screen? Currently there still is a space between screed edge and start of the ribbon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is caused by `elevation`, because CardView on android 21 use true `elevation` and your LinearLayout has 0 elevation so it is behind the CardView.

To solve this problem, you have 2 options

1. set android:elevation to your `LinearLayout`, e.g. `android:elevation="10px"`
2. wrap your `CardView` with a `FrameLayout` like below

   ```
   <FrameLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content">
       <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
               android:id="@+id/historicalWeightCardViewId"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="100dp"
               android:layout_marginTop="18dp" >

       </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
   </FrameLayout>

   <LinearLayout
           android:id="@+id/ribbonParentId"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="50dp"
           android:layout_gravity="left|top"
           android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
           android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark">

       <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:id="@+id/ribbonId"
               android:text="abc" />
   </LinearLayout>
   ```

Comment: I tried that, same result. CardView inside the RecycleView may be handled a little differently.

Comment: I have checked myself, it is caused by `android:elevation` on android 21+, please check my updated answer.

Comment: That was it - thanks. Now I have a weird shadow (because ribbon is not rectangular), but that's different issue.